# Iterate an array of objects within renderRow in ListView, React-Native

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native, axios, react-native-listview

having the code below, 
how can I display the various properties on the mobile screen?
I'm able to see the array of objects printed out on the console, but I'm not able to use the properties contained in each object in order to display the information on the mobile screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ListView, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Component5 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    this.state = {
      userDataSource: ds,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }
  fetchUsers() {
    axios.get('https://stageapi6.devmn.net/api/v1/forums/threads?topic_id=2418', {
      headers: {
        'client-id': '********'
      }
    })
    .then(response => this.setState({ userDataSource: this.state.userDataSource.cloneWithRows(response) }));
  }

  renderRow = (user) => {
    console.log(user); // => [Object, Object, Object, Object .........]

    return (
      <View>
        {/* I need a way to iterate the bojects and display the properties inside teh Text tags, the code below doesn't work */}
        <Text>{user.thread.num_posts}</Text> 
        <Text>{user.thread.topic_name}</Text>
        <Text>{user.thread.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
    render() {
      return (
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.userDataSource}
          renderRow={(user) => this.renderRow(user.threads)}
        />
      );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Component5', () => Component5);
```

[SCREENSHOT OF THE RETURNED ARRAY OF OBJECTS AND ITS PROPERTIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1016L.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the `user` array and build the jsx on the fly. use something like below

```
renderRow = (user) => {
 return (
  <View>
    { user.map(u =>
             (<View key={u.thread.id}>
              <Text>{u.thread.num_posts}</Text> 
              <Text>{u.thread.topic_name}</Text>
              <Text>{u.thread.name}</Text>
              <View>));
    }
  </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but unfortunately the error in the console is still the same `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. However I can see the iteration in user, but can't spit the properties on the simulator

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the previous answer but it should work. If it is giving you the error you posted above which says it `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` which goes to show that the `user` param you are passing into `renderRow` is not an array or its empty or it has a problem. Focus on solving that part.

I pasted the code snippet for the `fetchUsers` function into Babel repl and this is what I saw.

[image]

It looks like the `this` you are referencing for the `this.state.userDataSource` is not the correct `this` to be referencing.

Hopefully, this helps somehow